# Set of points with positive distribution is at most countable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability measure $P$ so that the distribution measure is $\mu (B) = P(X\in B)$ for any Borel set $B$. Then prove that the set $D = \{c:\mu\{c\}>0 \}$ is at most countable.

I saw this come up in Durett when proving Portmaneau's Lemma, but it's not clear why this is true. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3230135/probability-of-singletons-in-with-an-uncountable-sample-space/3230168#3230168

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard trick here is to invoke the fact the rationals are countable and dense in the reals. For each positive real number $x$, define

$$ D_x = \{ c : \mu\{ c \} > x \} $$

Then, $D$ can be written as a *countable* union of these sets; e.g.

$$ D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} D_{1/n} $$

So, if you can show that $D_x$ is countable for every $x > 0$, or even just for $D_{1/n}$, then $D$ is a countable union of countable sets and therefore countable.

Comment: Just to make sure, is each $D_x$ finite? It seems that being infinite would contradict $\mu\Omega = 1$.

Comment: @AndrewYuan: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $D$ is uncountable, then there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that
$\{c | \mu \{c\} \ge \epsilon \}$ is uncountable, but thus contradicts $
\mu \Omega = 1$.

Comment: I guess the difficult step to the OP here would be to show that "then there is some ϵ>0 such that..."

Comment: Since they are working from Durett, I presumed this was fair game...