# Probability of singletons in with an uncountable sample space

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let us assume that we have a sample space $\Omega=[0,1]$. Why is it not possible to have all the singletons $\{x\}\in\Omega$ with non-zero probability measure.

I searched for an answer on this forum but I could not find an answer. Please point me to a thread which gives an answer or please  let me know as to why *all* the singletons of an uncountable sample space can never have non-zero probability measure. I know that only a countable number of them can have a non-zero probability measure but I do not have a proof for that.

Comment: The sum of any uncountably many positive numbers is always infinite.

Comment: If every singleton has non-zero chance, then just write the sample space as the union of all singletons. Try to measure both. Notice any contradictions now?

Comment: @Sangchul Lee. Your comment hinges on the fact that sum of uncountably many positive numbers is always infinite. Why is that even relevant here? A measurable space requires us to have countable additivity. There is no mention of sums over index sets with uncountable number of elements right? In spite of that, we can never have all the singletons to have a non-zero probability. Why is that?

Comment: @NapDLover Similar to the comment by Sangchul, you are hinting at the probability of the union being equal to summation over all the singletons. However, this need not hold for an uncountable index set. The definition of a measurable space requires *countable additivity* and there is no requirement on index sets which are uncountable. However, we can still not have all the singletons to have non-zero probability. Why is that?

Comment: Well, it is very relevant by the following reason: $$\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}P(\{\omega\})=\sup_{\substack{F\subseteq\Omega\\F\text{ finite}}}P(F),$$ hence even the uncountable sum is not so different from finite sum. In particular, if the LHS is infinite, the you can find a finite set $F$ for which $P(F) >1$, which gives the contradiction. (Of course, I am assuming that every Singleton is measurable.)

Comment: If you are interested in details then you can refer to this https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~anush/Courses/2018_S.Math574.ST/Other%20files/Lutzer%20D%20--%20Stationary%20sets%20in%20omega_1,%20Ulam%20matrices,%20and%20probability%20measures.pdf

Comment: @Sanchul Lee. Thanks for explaining the reason. I did not know about this result.

Comment: @Soumyadip. I will definitely read the material that you have mentioned. Thank you for point me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume this was the case. Consider the following partition of $\Omega$ into countably many sets:
$$
A_n = \left\{x \in \Omega : 1/(n+1)\leq \mathbb{P}(\{x\}) \lt 1/n)\
\right\}
$$
Then, this forms a disjoint union of $\Omega$, so that:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\Omega) = \sum_{ n =1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_n) = 1
$$
Now, for every singleton the set, $\mathbb{P}(x) \geq 1/(n+1)$ for some $n$. Fix $n$ and consider $A_n$.  If this set had infinitely many (say countably many elements), then already we would have that $\mathbb{P}(A_n) = \infty$ as we would be summing $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty 1/(n+1)$ (here $n$ is fixed). Thus, each set has finitely many elements, and so $\Omega$ is a countable union of finite sets, ergo countable.

Note that the proof by contradiction was unnecessary here, but I have kept it for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This is exactly what I was looking for. A crisp proof pretty much from the basics showing why it is not possible to have all the singletons of an uncountable sample space to have non-zero probability measure. I greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: Sure, no problem!